# Get Object Properties from Array<string> values

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Thanks in advance,

I have the following Array with different strings which match with different properties and positions into an object.

```
(5) ["payments[0]", "payments[0].bills[0]", "payments[1]", "payments[1].bills[0]", "payments[1].bills[1]"]
```

Object model is something like this and I need to access to every object into arrays(payments and bills) and get the key/values for each one :

Exception: In the case of payments I won't get the value of bills property

```
{"payments": [
 {
  "bills": [
    {
      "account": "1e329a4b-6c87-4001-bc84-5ef6214fa3ec",
      "amount": "3243.00",
      "autopay": false,
      "bill": "b872f2ab-e446-4038-ae10-e0f94f8e4052",
      "payment": "46413743-7849-44ed-8d9b-5b037bb6327e",
      "customerReference": "Reference Customer",
      "important": null
    }
  ],
  "totalAmount": "3243.00",
  "guid": "46413743-7849-44ed-8d9b-5b037bb6327e"
},
{
  "bills": [
    {
      "account": "1e329a4b-6c87-4001-bc84-5ef6214fa3ec",
      "amount": "234.00",
      "autopay": false,
      "bill": "8cf5e681-eb70-43cd-824c-0a8535ad3456",
      "payment": "3036bf6c-8919-4d30-a494-05493969988e",
      "customerReference": "Reference customer",
      "important": null
    },
    {
      "account": "1e329a4b-6c87-4001-bc84-5ef6214fa3ec",
      "amount": "234.00",
      "autopay": false,
      "bill": "8cf5e681-eb70-43cd-824c-0a8535ad3456",
      "payment": "3036bf6c-8919-4d30-a494-05493969988e",
      "customerReference": "Reference customer",
      "important": null
    }
  ],
  "totalAmount": "234.00",
  "guid": "3036bf6c-8919-4d30-a494-05493969988e"
}]}
```

After this, I need to create a request like this:

someURL/?payments[0].totalAmount=234&payments[0].bill[0].account=1e329a4b-6c87-4001-bc84-5ef6214fa3ec&payments[0].bill[0].account=234&ayments[0].bill[0].autopay=false&...

Any Idea of how implement this ?

Thanks,

Comment: Sounds like there ought to be an easier solution to this problem. Is there no way that you can know what values are in the array the moment you are creating the object with the "payments[0]" etc. values? I mean the moment where `(5) ["payments[0]", "payments[0].bills[0]", "payments[1]", "payments[1].bills[0]", "payments[1].bills[1]"]` is constructed is where you know what you're going to need; maybe try to access the data that is in the target array at that point as well?

Comment: Thanks, for your answer. I build the first Array but If you find it easier, think that we have that object and I must get a request as below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you'll have to parse the string and get a path to your value. Using a function like this:

```
function parsePath(str) {
    var byDot = str.split(".");
    return byDot.reduce(function(path, part) {
        var byBracket = part.split("[");
        byBracket.forEach(function(part) {
           path.push(part.replace("]", ""));
        });
        return path;
    }, []);
}
```

Which, for example, returns `["payments", "0", "bills", "0", "account"]` if the string passed to it is `"payments[0].bills[0].account"`. You can add a check inside `byBracket.forEach` to see if the subscript is a string or not and remove the quotes surrounding it, although that doesn't seem necessary as all the subscripts in your example appear to be numbers.

Then resolve the value using a function like:

```
function resolve(obj, path) {
    return path.reduce(function(value, part) {
        if(value && value.hasOwnProperty(part)) {
            return value[part];
        }
    }, obj);
}
```

Which traverses the object level by level using the parts from the `path` array.

**Usage:**

```
var value = resolve(myObject, parsePath(myString));
```

**Example:**

```js
function parsePath(str) {
    var byDot = str.split(".");
    return byDot.reduce(function(path, part) {
        var byBracket = part.split("[");
        byBracket.forEach(function(part) {
           path.push(part.replace("]", ""));
        });
        return path;
    }, []);
}

function resolve(obj, path) {
    return path.reduce(function(value, part) {
        if(value && value.hasOwnProperty(part)) {
            return value[part];
        }
    }, obj);
}

var myObject = {"payments":[{"bills":[{"account":"1e329a4b-6c87-4001-bc84-5ef6214fa3ec","amount":"3243.00","autopay":false,"bill":"b872f2ab-e446-4038-ae10-e0f94f8e4052","payment":"46413743-7849-44ed-8d9b-5b037bb6327e","customerReference":"Reference Customer","important":null}],"totalAmount":"3243.00","guid":"46413743-7849-44ed-8d9b-5b037bb6327e"},{"bills":[{"account":"1e329a4b-6c87-4001-bc84-5ef6214fa3ec","amount":"234.00","autopay":false,"bill":"8cf5e681-eb70-43cd-824c-0a8535ad3456","payment":"3036bf6c-8919-4d30-a494-05493969988e","customerReference":"Reference customer","important":null},{"account":"1e329a4b-6c87-4001-bc84-5ef6214fa3ec","amount":"234.00","autopay":false,"bill":"8cf5e681-eb70-43cd-824c-0a8535ad3456","payment":"3036bf6c-8919-4d30-a494-05493969988e","customerReference":"Reference customer","important":null}],"totalAmount":"234.00","guid":"3036bf6c-8919-4d30-a494-05493969988e"}]};

var strings = ["payments[0]", "payments[0].bills[0]", "payments[1]", "payments[1].bills[0]", "payments[1].bills[1]", "payments[0].totalAmount", "payments[0].bills[0].account", "payments[0].bills[0].account", "payments[0].bills[0].autopay"];

strings.forEach(function(str) {
    console.log(str + ": " + resolve(myObject, parsePath(str)));
});
```